# How does firebase cloud storage free tier works?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have been going through the Firebase and Google Cloud storage docs, I can't seem to wrap my head around the free tier.

I want to ask if the 5GB free is for every month or just once before I start paying the usual fee?

As in do I get a limit of 5GB monthly or once I surpassed the 5GB I start paying regardless of the month or period?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to ask if the 5GB free is for every month or just once before I start paying the usual fee?

As it's specified in the [Cloud Storage pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), those 5GB represents the total space. It's **not** monthly. Once you get over that limit you'll have to pay $0.026/GB as it's specified there.

Comment: I am still confused about pricing between Google Cloud Storage vs Firebase Cloud Storage. Does FCS charges $0.026/GB in all regions it doesn’t matter which regions?? Also GCS also offers free egress in some regions up to 100GB does Firebase charge you not matter what region?

Comment: @Xenolion For pricing questions, I recommend you contact Firebase/Google Cloud support.